# Comparing two rows of a column in a bam file with awk

Tags: unix, awk

I am trying to compare two rows of a single column in a bam file. First to find matching entries in column 1, then, if the entries in column 1 match, to compare column 2 and find entries that do not match.

In order to read the file and retain the header, I first have to open the file and pipe it, then preserve in the same format with the command:

```
samtools -h file.bam | command I need here > file_filtered.bam
```

The header is multiple lines, not just a single line.  All the header lines start with '@'.

After the header, the bam file looks like this:

```
00b27c71-a833-4605-9fb3-a2714ac98091    ENST00000352983.6   157 60  16
00b27c71-a833-4605-9fb3-a2714ac98091    ENST00000258424.2   12  60 2048
00d77e65-466e-4fe6-ad0f-bc6b3f44af75    ENST00000367142.4   8   60 0
00d77e65-466e-4fe6-ad0f-bc6b3f44af75    ENST00000367142.4   130 12  4
```

I want to find rows that match in the first column but not in the second column, as in the first two rows above. The last two rows match on column 1, but also in column 2, so this is not of interest to me. The desired output from the above would be only the first two rows:

```
00b27c71-a833-4605-9fb3-a2714ac98091    ENST00000352983.6   157 60  16
00b27c71-a833-4605-9fb3-a2714ac98091    ENST00000258424.2   12  60 2048
```

I have tried a number of awk variations but to no avail.  There are many more columns and I would like to print all columns for the rows matching the criteria.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: @csijcs, It is not at all clear, as Cyrus mentioned please do add sample output to your post too in code tags `{}` button.

Comment: I have edited.  I want to find all rows that match in column 1, but not in column 2, and print all columns for those rows (there are many more masked columns tat are not of interest for the comparison)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you. It reads the Input_file 2 times.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"}FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]++;next} a[$1,$2]==1' Input_file  Input_file
```

***EDIT:*** Since OP told in comments that OP is passing a command's output to `awk` and OP didn't show that command too then you could use following.

```
your_command | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"}FNR==1{print;next}{a[$1,$2]++;b[$1,$2]=$0} END{for(i in a){if(a[i]==1){print i,b[i]}}}'
```

***EDIT2:*** To keep headers as per OP adding this solution now.

```
your_command | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"}FNR==1||/^@/{print;next}{a[$1,$2]++;b[$1,$2]=$0} END{for(i in a){if(a[i]==1){print b[i]}}}'
```